# How to address a dynamic element name in a for loop?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a general angular dart question that araised in a specific popup case for me:
How do I use the angular dart's # special operator in a loop?

In my case, I have a list of users for whom I want to open a popup with details on click. I use a popupSource directive which computes automatically the Rectangle **#subjectParticipant** from which the popup opening was triggered to display it next to its source.

The issue is that it seems to take the last rectangle of the loop : all users popups open in the same position

```
<li *ngFor="let activeUser of subject.users" >
  <div class="profileImg"
       (click)="popupUserInfoId = activeUser.userId"
       popupSource #subjectParticipant="popupSource">
    <img src="/auth/user/photo/s/{{activeUser.userId}}">
  </div>

  <info-popup *ngIf="popupUserInfoId == activeUser.userId"
              [userId]="popupUserInfoId"
              [source]="subjectParticipant" 
              [offsetX]="28" 
              [offsetY]="10" 
              [visible]="popupUserInfoId == activeUser.userId" >
  </info-popup>
</li>
```

My understanding is that dart angular overwrites the variable under **#subjectParticipant**  n times and only keeps the last one o the loop. Is there a way to append something dynamic (eg. the user index) to this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope should be within `<li>` and for each `<li>` there should be a different `subjectParticipant` value being maintained.
I suspect your issue comes from somewhere else.
If `popupSource` contains unique values, then this should be easy to debug by adding

```
<div>{{subjectParticipant.uniqueid}}</div>
```

inside `*ngFor` and checking if it renders different values for each `activeUser`.

Comment: I'm using material-popup which in turn uses PopupSourceDirective to retain the info of the popup trigger rectangle. 

When I try what you suggested, I get this error : 
EXCEPTION: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'PopupSourceDirective' has no instance getter 'uniqueid'.

Comment: That's expected. You could try with a custom directive instead of `popupSource` that actually provides an unique id, just to be able to investigate properly whether `#subjectParticipant` is per `activeUser` or for the whole `*ngFor` rendered HTML. I'm sure it's the former.
I don't know how to track down the actual issue you're trying to solve though.

Comment: You were right, I was putting the popupSource t of the loop for this concrete popup list I was having trouble with

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to make it work :) Thanks for the feedback.